# How to use Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearch API/Namespace?

Tags: uwp, maps, microsoft-account

The following page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.localsearch says:

"The LocalSearch namespace is not available to all Windows apps unless your developer account is specially provisioned by Microsoft. For more information about the Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearch namespace, please work with your Microsoft Account Team representative."

Does somebody have a similar experience or understand what we have to do?
I'm asking this question here because it's faster to get an answer than asking the question to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You may need talk to your local **Microsoft Developer Evangelist** and they should be able to get you in touch with the right person to help. If you do not know how to contact with the Microsoft Developer Evangelist, you could use [MS Contact Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) and ask them the relevant information.